# 100% height not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm currently having some problems displaying divs with 100% height in IE, it works fine in every other browser, it's just IE that is giving me some trouble and I'm not sure how to resolve it.
Here's some of my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="content">

    <div id="box-01" class="slide" style="color: #F26964; background-color: #003218;">
        <div class="text-content">
TEXT GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="box-02" class="slide" style="color: #F2F1EF; background-color: #70858E;">

            <div class="text-content">
TEXT GOES HERE
            </div>
    </div>


    <div id="box-03" class="slide" style="color: #F2F1EF; background-color: #003218">

            <div class="text-content">
TEXT GOES HERE
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    border:none
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;

    background: no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.text-content {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
}
```

So I have a set of relatively positioned divs, each one fitting to the browser window size, like I say this all works fine in every browser except IE, in particular the 100% height style attribute not being recognised.
After doing a little bit of research I found that this may have something to do with the text being in a table (which is necessary as I want to centre the text horizontally and vertically) but I've not got a clue how this issue can be resolved, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can centre a `<div>` horizontally and vertically without using a table. You should only really use tables to display tabular data.

Comment: In case you didn't know about it, display table-block is a better way to center verticaly. It doesn't work on ie7 but it can come in handy when you don't need 100% compatibility with this almost dead browser.

Comment: @GarryCairns yes, IE is a browser I never use btw, but it seems some people still do (unfortunately). So would the tables be the issue with IE?

Comment: @user1374796 I doubt the table is causing the problem, which is why I posted as a comment rather than an answer, but tables make your content less accessible so I'd always recommend avoiding them as a layout device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of strategies discussed here:
http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

This appears to work in IE FF & Chrome:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/asqpL